# Eclipse plugin developed under Indigo will work under Juno (Eclipse 4)?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I will start a new project as an Eclipse Plugin, but I found that a new major update of Eclipse will come at June. So I'm wondering, do I have to start developing on this new version or I can use Indigo to create my plugin then it can be be supported by Juno with no problem?

Thanks.

Comment: It depends on what your plug-in does and what architectural changes the Eclipse team made in Eclipse 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download Eclipse 4.2 for plug-in developers right now.

http://eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-rcp-and-rap-developers/junom6

You don't have to use the 4.2 platform, but you can read the documentation, especially the changes from Eclipse 3 to Eclipse 4, and see if this impacts your plug-in.